# How to run and get Solidity Coverage report in Scaffold-Eth?

Tags: solidity, code-coverage, hardhat

I am using Scaffold-eth (https://github.com/scaffold-eth/scaffold-eth).

With that, I can run things like:

```bash
yarn test
```

But I can't run:

```bash
yarn coverage
```

out of the gate (see `package.json` for all commands).

How can I get a coverage report?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that I had to do this:

Add the following to your `package.json` file under `"scripts"`:

```
"coverage": "cd packages/hardhat && npx hardhat coverage --network hardhat"
```

Then, install `Solidity-coverage` in your environment:

```
cd packages/hardhat && yarn workspace @scaffold-eth/hardhat add solidity-coverage --dev
```

(basically follow these steps: https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage but in your yarn workspace)

And add the coverage module to your `hardhat` config file `packages/hardhat/hardhat.config.js`:
`require('solidity-coverage');`

That should work.

---

Now you can run:

`yarn coverage` from the root folder and a coverage report will appear.